# Sending body to Options method by SoapUI

Tags: rest, soap, groovy, soapui

I trying to send the body code to some **OPTIONS** method with body parameters through SoapUI but i don't have idea how i could do this in order to do some automatic test by groovy.
Some with experience with this could help me?

I appreciate with this guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `New REST Method` dialog the `OPTIONS` verb is missing, so create a new method with one of the other verbs and then use the context menu `Show Method Viewer` to change it to `OPTIONS`.

[image: optionsMethod]